# Replace pickup roller on Canon mf8080cw, cannot access service menu

Tags: printer, maintenance, laser-printer

I have a Canon mf8080cw printer that I need to change the tray pickup roller (not the ADF).  This roller needs to be rotated in order to be removed.  It is my understanding that this is done through a service menu on the front of the printer.  I have been able to access the service menu by pressing MENU 2 8 MENU and that gets me into the service menu.  I cannot find the command for rotating the pickup roller.  The HP version of this printer indicates there is also a 2nd service menu, but I have not been able to find it.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should fix the problem:

1. Turn ON the power switch.
2. Execute the following items in Service mode.
   `COPIER` > `FUNCTION` > `VIFFNC` > `FD-R-CHG`
3. The Pickup Roller rotates and stops at the replacement position.
4. Disconnect the Inlet Connector.
5. Remove the cassette.